# Architecturally, how are iPhone applications installed from the AppStore?

Tags: iphone

When we hit that "install now" button via the AppStore, I am curious what is the process behind getting the app onto the iPhone?

Does it download a compressed zip? pkg? and does a XCOPY equivalent ?

Answer (score 8):

It downloads an `IPA` file which is technically a zipped file that contains the app along with DRM signatures and other stuff. It deploys the app by copying the folder to `/var/mobile/Applications/{GUID}/`.

Comment: If you're curious to see the contents of an IPA file, it is really just a ZIP file.